# Using ionic, Ilist view back and front

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, infinite-scroll

Using ionic, 
I had created a list, 
which I select a item from list, 
it should detail screen,
If i press back again I am showing the List,
But I am not focusing already selected item in the list,
It is possible to find and set focus,
but I don't want to reload the data and screen, as i have more data to load.

Do you we have any other option other then reloading the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-class="{'active': selectedIndex == $index}" ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-click="view(fruit, $index)">
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.view = function(fruit, index){
    $scope.selectedIndex = index;
    $state.go("view", {
        id: fruit.id
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but my question was different, While come back from view my mail list getting reloading,how to prevent from reloading